# django shop app model definition

Tags: django, django-models, model, many-to-many

I am trying to make a shop app.
I have the following models

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Order(models.Model):
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

So what i want to achieve is add many items in one order but i would also want to specify the quantity of each item in the order but i cannot figure out a good way to do it. I thought of overriding `save()` after creating an order and create a custom form requesting a quantity for each item added. But maybe there is a better/easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

> When you’re only dealing with simple many-to-many relationships such
>   as mixing and matching pizzas and toppings, a standard ManyToManyField
>   is all you need. However, sometimes you may need to associate data
>   with the relationship between two models.

and

> For these situations, Django allows you to specify the model that will
>   be used to govern the many-to-many relationship. You can then put
>   extra fields on the intermediate model. The intermediate model is
>   associated with the ManyToManyField using the through argument to
>   point to the model that will act as an intermediary. For our musician
>   example, the code would look something like this:

So we need another model. Shall we call it `OrderItem`?

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

There after just change your many to many field to be

```
item = models.ManyToManyField(Item,through='OrderItem')
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks exactly what i was looking for. I will try it and let you know!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! I added OrderItemInline as inline when i create an Order and i have exactly what i wanted. My only question now is if it possible to make the "item" field searchable and not just a dropdpwn list?

Comment: To add search functionality i finally made a form and added it to OrderItemInline

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply in time.